# How set [(ngModel)] in the bootstrap model

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to set get selected data from my drop-down menu using `ngModel`.
This is my template:

```
<div class="btn-group"
                             dropdown>
                            <button id="button-basic"
                                    dropdownToggle
                                    type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle"
                                    aria-controls="dropdown-basic"
                                    [(ngModel)]="size"
                                    ngDefaultControl 

                                    >
                                Size
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul id="dropdown-basic"
                                *dropdownMenu
                                class="dropdown-menu"
                                role="menu"
                                aria-labelledby="button-basic"


                                >
                                <li role="menuitem">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" >
                                        XS
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li role="menuitem">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" >
                                        S
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li role="menuitem">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item">
                                        M
                                    </a>
                                </li>


                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

This is my variable:   `public size:string;`

Update: I used select option

```
  <select class="custom-select" [(ngModel)]="this.product.size" >
                                <option *ngFor="let size of sizeArray; let i = index"  >
                                    {{size}}
                                </option>
                            </select>
```

Comment: First of all use select and option tag for dropdowns.Ul is not recommended at all!.I can show the implementation for select tag.

Answer (score 2):

## Bootstrap Section

There is no reason whatsoever to have NgModel on the anchor elements of the bootstrap menu. The menu is meant to redirect you somewhere in the website, thus you need not have it anywhere in your Form (where NgModel naturally resides).

What you might be looking for though is https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/ - The Example select section

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select [(ngModel)]="size" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
      <option>S</option>
      <option>XL</option>
      <option>XXL</option>
      <option>etc</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

## Angular FormsModule Section

This question is answered very well by varundhariyal. I will though, provide some more information as to the why this comment is the proper answer.

The NgModel can be applied to [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) FormControl implementations. This basically means that if you include the [FormsModule](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormsModule), you can use the NgModel two way binding on html **input** and **select** tags.

If you can't go any other way and you really must and need to use the above html, then you need to create your own **CUSTOM** FormControl.

This basically means that you need to use [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor#description) and create custom logic describing what it means to set a value or retrieve a value from your new FormControl. I will not provide the full solution here but basically you will have to create click events on your anchors that will set the value. You will need to implement the writeValue Which will have to apply the proper css so that the selected li will be the only one visible and so forth.

You can see an exmaple of that [here](https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/angular-build-custom-form-control/)

You can see how to pre-select a value for a select [at the stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-pre-select-value?file=src/app/app.component.html)

In summary you need following:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public sizeArray = ['SM', 'M', 'L', 'XL'];
  public product = {
    id: 1,
    size: 'L'
  };
}
```

Set a variable in the model that has a pre-set value.

Comment: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bare-bones-cva) of minimum required to set up control value accessor

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I have another question. How to set the first element from the array to be selected in my select option. I updated the question, you can see the code.

Comment: I updated the question and also included a stackblitz for you to see how the binding works!